# How to update a FrameLayout with a AlertDialog open?

Tags: android, view, refresh, visibility, android-framelayout

I need to update a text View and turn it visible with the text inputed on an AlertDialog, the problem is, after update and change from GONE to VISIBLE I want to save my FrameLayout as image, and share this content. My code is doing this all and it's working, but, because the AlertDialog the FrameLayout only refresh after the Dialog (and I need to refresh and save during this listener, to change to GONE again), what can I do? Already tried the .invalidate(), requestLayout() and .postInvalidate() ... and the .setOnDismissListener is only from API17.

This is the code:

fl is my frameLayout

```
public void actionShare(View v){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("What was the question ?");

    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    builder.setView(input);

    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            m_Text = "Question: " + input.getText().toString();
            tvQuestion.setText(m_Text);
            shareViewsVisible(true);
            fl.invalidate();
            fl.requestLayout();
            fl.postInvalidate();
            savingToShare();
            createShareDialog();
            shareViewsVisible(false);  
        }

    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }

    });


    builder.show();

}
```